# Apply a threshold to an image (quickly)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to build a pixel counting program that supports thresholding. I'd like users to be able to quickly generate a preview of the areas on an input image which the program will consider "positive" during quantitiation.

**Inputs:**

Input images will either be 24-bit RGB TIFF files (3 channels overlayed) or 16 bit greyscale TIFFs (one image per channel with greater bit depth). The user will select the type of images they're loading in ("mode" variable), which channel they're interested in ("desiredcolour" variable (0-2 for RGB)) and the threshold they'd like to use ("self.threshold" variable). Input image resolution is ~1400x1000.

**Output:**

On clicking a "Preview" button, the user chooses a file and a window pops up showing a preview of that image with positive pixels overlayed in light blue. I had trouble getting the 16-bit greyscale tiffs to display in the program window, so I've made it convert them into RGB while generating the preview. The ability to apply colour to the detected pixels is useful there. I've also had it resize the preview to a more convenient size.

While the script below works, ideally I'd like to have the preview image update as the threshold variable is changed by the user. The current script takes several seconds to generate an image and so that's not ideal.

The key functions I have so far are below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as tkfiledialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

#### Open preview window

```
def openpreview(self):
    global desiredcolour
    self.previewfile = Image.open(tkfiledialog.askopenfilename())
    self.logevent("Opening preview")
    self.genpreview(self.previewfile, desiredcolour)
```

#### Thresholded Preview Generator

```
def genpreview(self, tgt, value):
    global mode
    self.pixellist = list(tgt.getdata())
    self.newlist=[]
    if mode.get() == "RGB" and tgt.mode[0] == "I":
        self.logevent("Error: This is not an RGB file")
        return
    elif mode.get() == "RAW" and tgt.mode[0] != "I":
        self.logevent("Error: This doesn't look like a RAW file")
        return
    for point in self.pixellist:
        if mode.get() == "RGB":
            if point[value] >= self.threshold.get():
                point = (0, 191, 255)
            self.newlist.append(point)
        if mode.get() == "RAW":
            if point >= self.threshold.get():
                point = (0, 191, 255)
            else:
                point = point//255
                point = (point, point, point)
            self.newlist.append(point)
    self.preview = Image.new("RGB", tgt.size)
    self.preview.putdata(self.newlist)
    self.preview = self.preview.resize((tgt.size[0]//2, tgt.size[1]//2))
    self.preview = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.preview)
    self.preview_window(self.preview)
```

#### Diplay preview in new window

```
def preview_window(self, outgoingimage):
    self.previewwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    self.previewwindow.wm_attributes('-toolwindow',1)
    self.previewpane = tk.Label(self.previewwindow, image=outgoingimage)
    self.previewpane.image=outgoingimage
    self.previewpane.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

I'm wondering if I'm approaching this the wrong way and there's a more efficient way to do all this? Or perhaps there's a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to a few different approaches the fastest I eventually came up with has been using the Numpy and opencv packages. Working with arrays rather than looping through pixels is much more efficient, with this version taking ~0.05s per image rather than ~0.9s for the script above.

#### Thresholded Preview Generator

```
def genpreview(self, tgt, value):
    activemode = mode.get()
    thold = threshold.get()
    imfile = cv2.imread(tgt, -1)
    if activemode == "RGB" and imfile.dtype != "uint8":
        self.logevent("Error: This is not an RGB file")
        return
    elif activemode == "RAW" and imfile.dtype != "uint16":
        self.logevent("Error: This doesn't look like a RAW file")
        return
    if activemode == "RGB":
        mask = (imfile[:,:,value] > thold)
        imfile[mask] = (0, 191, 255)
        self.preview2 = Image.fromarray(imfile, 'RGB')
        self.preview = self.preview2.resize((self.preview2.size[0] // 2, self.preview2.size[1] // 2))
    elif activemode == "RAW":
        im = cv2.imread(tgt)
        mask = (im[:,:,1] > thold//256)
        im[mask] = (0, 191, 255)
        self.preview2 = Image.fromarray(im, 'RGB')
        self.preview = self.preview2.resize((self.preview2.size[0] // 2, self.preview2.size[1] // 2))
    self.preview = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.preview)
```

For inputs "tgt" is just a string of the target file's path and "value" is the index of the channel being analysed.